# Como pintar un lienzo en java

Tags: java, canvas

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de dibujo en java donde solo dibuje cuadrados con el mouse. El problema es que no se como se usa el metodo paint(Graphics g) de la clase Graphics. Ejemplo: quiero pintar un cuadrado en el lienzo en la coordenada x_inicial, y_inicial, x_final, y_final mediante el metodo paint pero no se como llamarlo porque la clase Graphics es abstracta y no se como llamar al metodo paint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo:

**Clase Cuadrado:**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Square extends JPanel
{
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
   {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      g.drawRect( 10 * 10, 10 * 10,  25 * 10, 25 * 10 );
   }
}
```

**Clase Main:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SquareMain
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      Square panel = new Square();

      JFrame application = new JFrame(); 

      application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      application.add( panel ); 
      application.setSize( 500, 500 );
      application.setVisible( true ); 
   } 
}
```